# Tkinter plotting slowing down in thread

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading, tkinter-canvas

My code is below. The goal is to plot multiple random walks on to a FigureCanvasTkAgg.

I didn't add the code for my custom Thread class based on `threading.Thread` but it simply repeats the input function on an infinite loop from `.starting()` to `.stopping()` which can be bound to buttons.

What I find is the plotting becomes slower the further the loop runs. I believe the bottleneck is in `ax.plots(s)`, `plots.show()`, as I understand, this method effectively plots every previous plot again. This was assumed as I can call `ax.clear()` to speed up the loop again.

Is there a different way I should be updating this image to optimize for just plotting without clearing?

(Not as interested in optimizing the rest as they do not seem to change per loop so can't explain the slow down situation, open to correction)

```
import numpy as np
import threading
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def Updater(ax,plots):
    s = np.zeros(400)
    for i in range(399):
        s[i+1]=s[i]+random.choice([-1, 1])
    ax.plot(s)
    plots.show()

tk = Tk()
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

plots = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,tk)
plots.get_tk_widget().pack()

Thread(lambda ax=ax,plots=plots: Updater(ax,plots)).starting()
tk.mainloop()
```